# Why Protection() Constructor is getting executed multiple times? (Especially, base constructor getting executed twice in the beginning of the output)

Tags: java

The Package p1 has 3 classes: Protection, Derived, and SamePackage. The Protection class has 4 variables each defined with a unique type of access modifier.Each subsequent class tries to access the variables in an instance of this class.

```
package p1;
public class Protection {
    int n = 1;
    private int n_pri = 2;
    protected int n_pro = 3;
    public int n_pub = 4;
    public Protection() {
        System.out.println("base constructor");
        System.out.println("n = " + n);
        System.out.println("n_pri = " + n_pri);
        System.out.println("n_pro = " + n_pro);
        System.out.println("n_pub = " + n_pub);
    }
}
//This is file Derived.java:
package p1;
class Derived extends Protection {
    Derived() {
        System.out.println("derived constructor");
        System.out.println("n = " + n);
        // class only
        // System.out.println("n_pri = "4 + n_pri);
        System.out.println("n_pro = " + n_pro);
        System.out.println("n_pub = " + n_pub);
    }
}

//This is file SamePackage.java:
package p1;
class SamePackage {
    SamePackage() {
        Protection p = new Protection();
        System.out.println("same package constructor");
        System.out.println("n = " + p.n);
        // class only
        // System.out.println("n_pri = " + p.n_pri);
        System.out.println("n_pro = " + p.n_pro);
        System.out.println("n_pub = " + p.n_pub);
    }
}
//Test File
// Demo package p1.
package p1;
// Instantiate the various classes in p1.
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Protection ob1 = new Protection();
        Derived ob2 = new Derived();
        SamePackage ob3 = new SamePackage();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following Output

```
base constructor
n = 1
n_pri = 2
n_pro = 3
n_pub = 4
base constructor
n = 1
n_pri = 2
n_pro = 3
n_pub = 4
derived constructor
n = 1
n_pro = 3
n_pub = 4
base constructor
n = 1
n_pri = 2
n_pro = 3
n_pub = 4
same package constructor
n = 1
n_pro = 3
n_pub = 4
```

Comment: Did you expect other results? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Protection constructor gets executed multiple times because you instantiate multiple objects of Protection.

Each time you call `new Protection();` the Protection constructor runs.

You call it first in Demo, then you instantiate Derived and since Derived extends Protection so the Protection constructor gets called once more. And finally when you instantiate SamePackage and SamePackage instantiates Protection as well, the constructor gets called a third time.

I hope this is understandable...

Comment: thanks for the explanation...
I have an additional doubt:
why is base constructor getting executed twice in the beginning of the output?

Comment: Because you first instantiate Protection (the first output) and then Derived. And because Derived extends Protection, the Protection constructor gets executed first and then the Derived constructor.

Comment: Got it...Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to help. I would be grateful if you could accept the answer, so others can see that there is a solution for your problem.

Comment: Even if `Derived` had a constructor, the constructor of `Protection` would still get called.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You're right. Fixed it!